# How to completely remove an old installation of java?

Tags: windows-7, java

I had an old installation of Java on my computer in the directory:

> C:\programs\java\jdk7

and another one in

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Java\jre7

When I was cleaning my computer I deleted these folders (instead of using the java uninstaller) and now if I remove all current versions of java (I have the 1.8 JDK+JRE) and try to run `java -version` I get an error stating that:

> Error: could not open C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Java\jre7\lib\i386\jvm.cfg'

or if I try to run a clojure program using Leiningen I get another error complaining about the missing

> C:\programs\java\jdk7

folder.

I tried to run the official **Oracle java uninstaller** but it did not find any leftovers. I checked the **registry** for keys and the **environmental variables** but there is no reference to these installations either. How can I remove these references to non-extistent java versions on my computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How do I completely remove an old installation of java?

Please try [JavaRa](https://singularlabs.com/software/javara/):

> JavaRa is an effective way to deploy, update and remove the Java
>   Runtime Environment (JRE). It can assist in repairing or removing Java
>   when other methods fail.
>
> [image]
>
> **Its most significant feature is the
>   JRE Removal tool; which forcibly deletes files, directories and
>   registry keys associated with the JRE.**

---

#### Disclaimer

I am not affiliated with [JavaRa](https://singularlabs.com/software/javara/) in any way, I am just an end user of the software.